# How to develop chart on sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

When creating bar chart on sencha touch I get this exception.

> 06-25 12:59:57.245: E/Web Console(28577): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CartesianChart' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:9

My index file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Phone gap & sencha  </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/touch/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script >

 var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
    data: [
        {'name':'metric one', 'data1':10, 'data2':12, 'data3':14, 'data4':8, 'data5':13},
        {'name':'metric two', 'data1':7, 'data2':8, 'data3':16, 'data4':10, 'data5':3},
        {'name':'metric three', 'data1':5, 'data2':2, 'data3':14, 'data4':12, 'data5':7},
        {'name':'metric four', 'data1':2, 'data2':14, 'data3':6, 'data4':1, 'data5':23},
        {'name':'metric five', 'data1':27, 'data2':38, 'data3':36, 'data4':13, 'data5':33}
    ]
});

new Ext.chart.Chart({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    animate: true,
    store: store,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['data1'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        title: 'Sample Values',
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['name'],
        title: 'Sample Metrics'
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'bottom',
        highlight: true,
        tips: {
          trackMouse: true,
          width: 140,
          height: 28,
          renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
            this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + ' views');
          }
        },
        label: {
          display: 'insideEnd',
            field: 'data1',
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            color: '#333',
            'text-anchor': 'middle'
        },
        xField: 'name',
        yField: ['data1']
    }]
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem a few weeks ago. CartesianChart.js was missing.

Ensure CartesianChart.js is in the charts folder.